# Pandas conditional, contains, replace

Tags: python, pandas, replace, contains, pandas-loc

I am hoping someone can help me with this.

I have a df which I want to use replace on column 'Length' but I want to only use replace on certain rows which fit the criteria (which I have been able to do). The problem is the rows that do not fit the criteria which end up with n/a's but I really want to keep the existing data in those rows i.e. not run the replace method.

Here is the code to make the selection, criteria does not contain 'hour'.

```
mask = ~data['Length'].str.contains("hour")
```

This is my code for replacing which is working fine. I am writing over the original data.

```
data['Length'] = data.loc[mask, 'Length'].replace(r'([1])[h]\s', r'\1 hour ', regex=True)
data['Length'] = data.loc[mask, 'Length'].replace(r'([2-9]*)[h]\s', r'\1 hours ', regex=True)
data['Length'] = data.loc[mask, 'Length'].replace(r'([0-9]*)[m]', r'\1 minutes', regex=True)
```

Input data. Row 0 has the format I require in the original data. Other rows need to be run through the replace functions.

```
0    1 hour 30 minutes
1               2h 45m
2               4h 30m
3               1h 45m
4               1h 45m
5               1h 45m
6               1h 45m
7               1h 45m
```

Output currently, I want to keep the original data in row 0.

```
0                   NaN
1    2 hours 45 minutes
2    4 hours 30 minutes
3     1 hour 45 minutes
4     1 hour 45 minutes
5     1 hour 45 minutes
6     1 hour 45 minutes
7     1 hour 45 minutes
```

Now I am not married to the methods I have used so if there is a better way then I am open to suggestions, but hopefully there is something simple I am missing. It seems like it should be so simple as it's just an if-else. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must pass in the `mask` on the left side of your assignment as well:

```
# Add ".loc[mask, " on the left side:
data.loc[mask, 'Length'] = data.loc[mask, 'Length'].replace(r'([1])[h]\s', r'\1 hour ', regex=True)
data.loc[mask, 'Length'] = data.loc[mask, 'Length'].replace(r'([2-9]*)[h]\s', r'\1 hours ', regex=True)
data.loc[mask, 'Length'] = data.loc[mask, 'Length'].replace(r'([0-9]*)[m]', r'\1 minutes', regex=True)
```

Otherwise you are mutating the whole `data['Length']` column by assigning a filtered (lower-length) `series` to it, which makes the empty slots being auto-filled with `np.nan`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Felipe. I have tried that and got  
`TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed` Traceback `line 130, in time_format_change
    data[mask, 'Length'] = data.loc[mask, 'Length'].replace(r'([1])[h]\s', r'\1 hour ', regex=True)`

Comment: Are you sure you added the `loc` on the left side?

Answer (score 0):

When using those regular expressions to replace and then assigning the result to `data['Length']`, the original dataframe gets overwritten and the original value of the first row is lost, because a new (smaller) Series of length 7 goes into a length 8 Series, using the same indexes of `mask` (that's the reason the first row gets replaced by NaN)

Try with this:

```
mask = ~data['Length'].str.contains("hour") 

data[mask] = data.loc[mask].replace(r'([1])[h]\s', r'\1 hour ', regex=True)
data[mask] = data.loc[mask].replace(r'([2-9]*)[h]\s', r'\1 hours ', regex=True)
data[mask] = data.loc[mask].replace(r'([0-9]*)[m]', r'\1 minutes', regex=True)
```